# Angular Reactuve Form Control valueChanges get value changed field name , prev value and current value

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

```
 this.form = this.fb.group({ 
  prop1: '',
  prop2: ''
});

this.form.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null), pairwise())
  .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
    console.log('PREV2', prev);
    console.log('NEXT2', next);
  });
```

using this code I am able to get the previous value and current value. what I want is there any way to get which field is changed, prev value and current value.

like **field changed name: prop1, prev value:"", current value: "next value"**

Comment: Do you want to find json difference?

Comment: which form field value is changed that field name, prev value and current value

Comment: There's no build-in RxJS operator but I think lodash has some function for that.

Comment: I think you should remove `startWith` operator first and try again but this way will always get you the previous json form and the current json form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of subscribing to the`FormGroup.valueChanges` observable, you could subscribe to the `FormControl.valueChanges` observable. 
See https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl for the implementation.
This way you could have access to the control itself.
Maybe something like this?

```
Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
        this.form.controls[key].valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null), pairwise())
        .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
            console.log(key) // your FormControl Identifier 
            console.log('PREV2', prev);
            console.log('NEXT2', next);
        });
    });
```